# How to align a div element using the center of the page as a reference?

Tags: css, html

So I'm trying to get an element to align itself a certain percentage from the CENTER of the page.

So I've tried replacing where I'd usually put a percentage from either the left or the right with "center"

```
.aboutcredit {
     z-index:-100000;
     center:25%;
     top:75%;
     transform:translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
     position:fixed;
     text-align:center;
     vertical-align:middle;
}
```

but no luck.  Kind of what I'm trying to do here:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/SkLdMf7.png]

Comment: Like this http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/gk2u8unq/?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you have noticed, but `center:25%;` does nothing. You probably want `left:50%`. Seeing as you want it to be moved 25%, make it `left:75%;` and that should be what you're looking for. Like so:

```css
.aboutcredit {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: black;
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  left: 75%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%);
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="aboutcredit"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've run into this several times, and the way I do it is to:
1. Set the element to position absolute
2. set the element using percentages to the area where you would like it, to center on page it would be left:50%, margin-left: -{width / 2}, but in this case it is left:75%, margin-left: -{width / 2}

```
.box {
 height:400px;
 width:400px;
 border:1px solid black;
 left: 75%;
 margin-left:-200px;
 position: absolute;
 }
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/7j8DxiUUASrn8wQqBKNW?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

```
.aboutcredit {
    z-index:-100000;
    left:50%;
    top:50%;
    transform:translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
    position:fixed;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gerLkswu/1/